# Problem with wireless on Toshiba Satellite C55-C

Tags: networking, wireless, intel, toshiba-satellite

I'm relatively inexperienced with Linux.  I've done a number of installations, but they were all either pretty much straight out-of-the-box JEDI installations with a UFO box or installations on Raspberry Pi.

This is my first installation on a laptop.  The Toshiba C55-C-184 came with Windows 10 pre-installed.  I replaced this with Ubuntu 16.04 - I need to install ROS on Ubuntu for an online robotics course - however it looks like I'm failing at the first hurdle!

I've searched the forums and I've seen that several people have had problems with other Toshiba laptops, but I can't find anything that helps.  Other (earlier?) Toshiba laptops seem to have used Realtec controllers for wireless connectivity, and most of the solutions that I have seen seem to focus on that.  Unfortunately, this one seems to use an Intel controller, so those solutions just don't work.

I ran lspci -knn, and got this output:

```
lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev cb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8170]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

--

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1179:f840]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

The output from rfkill list all:

```
rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output from dmesg | grep iwl

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[   13.853351] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.047392] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   14.047499] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.047807] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.165552] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   15.122708] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   29.782151] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.782459] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.892142] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.892517] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Especially if you can explain ***why*** it's not working as well as ***how*** I can fix it.  I'm always happy to expand my working knowledge of Linux.

UPDATE:  Given how many posts I've seen about wifi problems on Toshiba laptops, and since I really cannot find anything to explain why I'm seeing this problem, I've posted a question with Toshiba support to see whether this is a known problem with Toshiba laptops.  Maybe they can suggest an answer ...

UPDATE2: Well, I got a reply from Toshiba support:

> "The issues you report are most likely software errors and in this
>   case we advise that you reinstall Windows 10."

Not exactly helpful, are they?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `rfkill list all`

Comment: I've added the results as requested @Jeremy31

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Added the results as requested @chili555

Comment: We see no reason at all that it is not working. Please tell us more. Does it see networks when you click the Network Manager icon? Does it see *your* network? Does it try and fail to connect? Does it connect and then drop? Or what, exactly??

Comment: It's not showing any wireless networks at all, even though it's within 2m of the wireless router.  My phone shows more than 10 networks available. As far as I can see, it's not connecting at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one point I thought that I'd found a solution using [wicd](https://launchpad.net/wicd) as an alternative to network manager, but the it turned out that the connection I was seeing was actually via wired Ethernet (I'd forgotten to unplug the cable. Note to self: don't try diagnosing problems when tired!).

In the end I gave up and sent the laptop back to Toshiba under warranty. It turns out that there was a problem with the laptop's cable harness which they had to  replace. It arrived back this morning and now WiFi is working perfectly.

Thank you all again for your help.